# $.ajax post Request header field Content-Type is not allowed CORS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am getting the following error while making a CORS request. Interestingly this is working in safari but not in google chrome and firefox. I have been looking through everything but haven't found any solution on the web.

I am trying to send json to server but as far as I know I need to make it string before sending it to the server so I am using JSON.stringify but at the end I am expecting json result from the server.

This is what I am getting on the curl call. (I just tried that to see the headers)

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 18 Apr 2017 15:13:04 GMT
Server: Apache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Max-Age: 21600
Content-Length: 213
Content-Type: application/json
```

and this is what I am getting on network tab in chrome

[image: network tab]

and the last part my code

```
    function foo(api_key, url, query, pdata, callback) {
        var result = 'none';
        if (typeof pdata != "undefined"){
            var mydata = {"api_key": api_key, "query": query, "data": pdata };
        }
        else {
            var mydata = {"api_key": api_key, "query": query};
        }
        $.ajax({
               method : "POST",
               url : url,
               data: JSON.stringify(mydata),
               contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
               cache: false,
               dataType: "json",
               success : function(data) {
               console.log("API call is working successfully!")
               callback(data);
               result = data  
         },
         error: function( data, status, error ) { 
               console.log("API call failed!")
         }
     });
     return result;
    }
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://my_url. Request header field   Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
api.js:29 API call failed!`
```

What should I do, change or add to make it work in chrome and firefox?

Comment: If your backend isn't picky about the request `Content-Type` header, you could always set it to `text/plain` which makes it a *simple* request and thus, avoids a pre-flight `OPTIONS` request

Comment: Try updating your options with `crossDomain: true`. This should be automatic, but maybe that fails?

Comment: Probably useful for future references, but please include textual content instead of simply posting screenshots/images of your code.

Comment: @Koen no, have you even read the documentation for that property?

Comment: @Phil what are you trying to say?

Comment: @Terry yes you are right, I am going to update them

Comment: @Phil changing the content-type on client didn't work out

Comment: @Koen I'm saying that the `crossDomain` property is not relevant here at all. You should read the documentation before blindly recommending it ~ http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Comment: @Phil it's more that I'm questioning the tone of your comment, and your assumption that I didn't read the documentation. Because I did read it, but may have misread something in it. And it wasn't a recommendation, it was a suggestion, hence the "maybe"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your ajax request seems to be correct but the problem is on server side. For every `cors` request browser send a **preflight** request. Only after **preflight** request gets validated through server side you can send cors ajax request.

So based on the type of your server you are using for **preflight** request you need to send proper response to browser.

Proper response means **set appropriate headers** on the preflight request's response and send it back to client i.e browser.

For `curl` request you don't need to do that, because curl request does not goes through preflight request validation on server side.

It's only needed in case of browser's due to security reasons.

An example could be like this -

```
    HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse(request.getProtocolVersion(), NO_CONTENT);
    HttpHeaders headers = response.headers();

    headers.set(HttpHeaders.Names.CONNECTION, HttpHeaders.Values.CLOSE);
    headers.set(CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
    headers.set(CACHE_CONTROL, "max-age=31536000, public");
    headers.set(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, request.headers().get("Origin"));
    headers.set(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS, "true");
    headers.set(ACCESS_CONTROL_MAX_AGE, "31536000");
    headers.set(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS, "POST, GET, OPTIONS");
    headers.set(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, request.headers().get("Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
    headers.set(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS, "true");
    send(response);
```

This is just an example but how you will do it on your side totally depends on your server side and server framework which you are using.

Comment: I realized that when I compare the response headers in safari and chrome. Content Type is coming as `application/json` in safari (as expected ) but in chrome content type is coming as `text/html; charset=utf-8 ` so so you have any idea how to prevent chrome doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually your `preflight` request is getting failed, as you are setting `content-type` but, no `Content-Type` header is present on response.

So, either don't set `content-type` to `json` instead use `text/plain, form-data` to bypass preflight request and directly send the ajax request to cross-domain server.

Or set `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type` header on server.

To set header on apache

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type"`

will work.

[image]

Comment: when I made API call through curl, I am seeing `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type` in the response. So that means it have been already set to`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type` right ?

Comment: Yes .. if its their in response. It will be their in request only .. if not set at server ..IN the image uploaded by you .. the header is in request only .. not present in response.

Comment: it is a flask project and I checked the server side and the options has been already set to `response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")` but I am still getting `Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

Comment: I realized that when I compare the response headers in safari and chrome. Content Type is coming as `application/json` in safari (as expected ) but in chrome content type is coming as `text/html; charset=utf-8 ` so so you have any idea how to prevent chrome doing this?

Comment: Did you set the response type externally to `application/json` from flesk ?

Comment: One better way is ...`avoid preflight request`, that `OPTIONS` one. To avoid you need to avoid settings content type from frontend.. So either send json as key value of form data and parse json using flesk.  OR send form data only. `Preflight` comes only when `content-type` is other than `text/plain, form-data`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved! everything on client side is correct

started to use CORS lib on the server

```
from flask_cors import CORS
```

and as @WitVault says configuring server with these settings solved my problem!

```
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
```